# .htaccess causing index.php to download with settings for using php5 version

Tags: php, .htaccess

My website is hosting on the commun server free.fr and the default php is php4. So I configure the .htaccess file to set the version of php to php5.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

The .htaccess file cause the download of index.php when I access to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The php version must also be installed on the server. If you are trying to use a handler that doesn't exist then there is nothing interpreting your php, so it is just being served up as text.

Comment: When I change the extension of php file to *.php5, it work well. So I think php5 is installed. However I want to active php5 by .htaccess and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your server has installed php5 you can make it with:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

This code activate PHP 5.4

If your server doesn't have installed PHP5 it is imposible.

Comment: When I change the extension of php file to *.php5, it work well. So I think php5 is installed. I have just modified my .htaccess with your code but i have the same problem, it causes the download of index.php

Comment: More precision. In .htaccess file, i have only this line and when I put it in comment, it works well.

Comment: Ok.. If your host doesn't provides you the posibilitie to change your PHP version from your panel, the bes option is to change to a host that do... Personally I use hostinger.com it's very complete in administrator functions and it allows you to choose your PHP version until PHP 5.4

Comment: Thanks very much. I have one solution is to rename all php file to php5 ... Is hostinger.com free ?

Comment: Yep, hostinger.com is totally free

Comment: Or try with this: AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php

Comment: with AddType .... it doesn't cause download but I think it doesn't active php5 because I still have error on my command "simplexml_load_file".